# Text overlapping on Xamarin.IOS table

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

As I said in other questions I am very newbie in `.Net` technologies. Now I am starting with an exercise using the Xamarin Crossplatform (Xamarin.IOS for the moment). But I have a problem with this code, it's working, but the method `ForceUpdateSize()` crashes the application if I have more than 6 elements in the table?. When I remove the method the app works fine, but then the text is overlapped.

This is the method that is filling my table:

```
public sealed class AutoViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        ViewCell vc = item as ViewCell;
        if (vc != null)
        {
            var sr = vc.View.Measure(tv.Frame.Width, double.PositiveInfinity, MeasureFlags.IncludeMargins);

            if (vc.Height != sr.Request.Height)
            {
                sr = vc.View.Measure(tv.Frame.Width, double.PositiveInfinity, MeasureFlags.IncludeMargins);
                vc.Height = sr.Request.Height;

                //vc.ForceUpdateSize(); --> Text ovelpping effect if I remove this method, but the app doesn't crash  
            }
        }
        return GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
    }

}
```

Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Hichem BOUSSETTA !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//vc.ForceUpdateSize(); --> Text ovelpping effect if I remove this method, but the app doesn't crash
tv.BeginUpdates();
tv.EndUpdates();
```

I have found this in an older post, but sadly I can't find it anymore.
Also take a look at this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4012
I think the Xamarin Community knows well about this and is addressing it in this Thread.